# Using self vs class name

Tags: ios, objective-c

An excerpt from CS193P PlayingCard.M

```
+ (NSArray *)rankStrings
{
    return @[@"?",@"A",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"J",@"Q",@"K"];
}
+(NSUInteger)maxRank{
    return [[self rankStrings] count]-1;
}
-(void)setRank:(NSUInteger)rank
{
    if(rank <= [PlayingCard maxRank])
    {
        _rank = rank;
    }
}
```

I understand that in the third method, you can't say

```
-(void)setRank:(NSUInteger)rank
{
    if(rank <= [self maxRank])
    {
        _rank = rank;
    }
}
```

because it is an instance method, so `self` will refer to an instance object which cannot use the `maxRank` method.

But in the `maxRank` implementation, wouldn't 
`return [[PlayingCard rankStrings] count]-1;`  be the same as

`return [[self rankStrings] count]-1;`

What is the difference?

Comment: The difference becomes significant when someone subclasses your `PlayinCard` class. It's better not to hard-code class names unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: You mean when a subclass chose to override `rankStrings` , using `self` in the superclass would keep them from having to reimplement `+maxRank` ?

Comment: it is a simple difference between _class_ methods and _instance_ methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference can be significant if someone subclasses your class. If they do, and overwrite your `maxRank` function, then the new definition will be used in the subclass rather than the one defined in the base class. If you want to force the subclass to use the bass class' definition of `maxRank`, then use the class name, otherwise, use `self`.

Comment: So if they change the `rankStrings` array in the subclass, calling `maxRank` would still give them `PlayingCard` `rankStrings` ?

Comment: No, if `maxRank` gets the `rankStrings` with `[self rankStrings]`. If it uses `[PlayingCard rankStrings]` then yes.